# Line Integrals, dx, dy and parameters

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So I posted a similar question the other day, which I answered myself since I was under the impression that I figured this stuff out. But today I found a question where my technique broke down and I have no idea why.

"Calculate $$\oint_c (3x^2y^2 + y^3)dx + (2x^3y + 6xy^2)dy$$ where the curve $c$ is the triangle with corners in $(0,0) (2,0) (2,2)$ oriented counterclockwise."

Using green's theorem we can solve this quickly, and get the answer 4. However, I wanted to make sure and redid my calculations without using greene's and got a completely different answer. Not quite sure what is going on.

So I parametrized the boundry of $c$, as three straight lines of the form $$<t,0> for\,\, 0\leq t \leq 2$$
$$<0,t> for\,\, 0\leq t \leq 2$$
$$<t,t> for\,\, 2\geq t \geq 0$$

Along the first curve ($c_1$) we get, for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = 1 and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ = 0  $$\int_c (3t^2(0)^2 + 0^3)(1) + (2t^3(0) + 6t(0)^2)(0) dt$$

which evaluates to zero.

Along the second curve ($c_2$) we get, for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = 0 and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ = 1  $$\int_c (3(0)^2t^2 + t^3)(0) + (2(0)^3(t) + 6(0)t^2)(1) dt$$

which, again, evaluates to zero.

Along the third curve ($c_3$) we get, for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = 1 and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ = 1  $$\int_c (3(t)^2t^2 + t^3)(1) + (2(t)^3(t) + 6(t)t^2)(1) dt$$
$$\int_2^0 5t^4 + 7t^3 dt = -60$$

Now at first I assumed I had messed up with the intepretation of the dx & dy terms, but when I looked it up the book noted the process as:

$$\oint_c\mathbb{F}\bullet d\Bbb{r} = \int_a^b \mathbb{F}\bullet \frac{d\Bbb{r}}{dt}dt = \int_a^b [ \ F_1(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dx}{dt} + F_2(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dy}{dt} + F_3(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dz}{dt} \ ] dt$$

which is exactly the way I think about it! So yeah, where did I mess up?

Comment: Your second curve should be $<2,t>$, for $0 \leq t \leq 2$.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right. The weird thing is that I had made that mistake earlier, corrected it, but then gotten the wrong answer becuse I made a mistake in the third integral. But then when redid it with the  corrected the third integral, I forgot to fix the second one! But yeah, now it works out perfectly! Thanks, sorry for wasting your time!